# How to disable long-press animation of context menu for CollectionView iOS Swift?

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview, long-press, uicontextmenuconfiguration

My ViewController have the three UICollectionView for all the UICollectionView I did create contextMenu, but for the last UICollectionView I am don't want to show the menu and for <return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil)> all work well but for this UICollectionview animation of long-press didn't disabled.

How to disable the animation of the long press for the last UICollectionView? It does be easy but I can't delete the default case.

Example of my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        
        switch collectionView {
        case favoriteCollectionView:
             return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) {...}
        case allCollectionView:
             return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) {...}
        default:
              // This menu empty and doesn't show but the animation of long pressed not disabled how to fix this?
             return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `return nil` insted of `return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil)`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {

    switch collectionView {
    case favoriteCollectionView:
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) {...}
    case allCollectionView:
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) {...}
    default:
        return nil //<-- HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is works well :). I did try the same in the past and in my case, it didn't work, but now it is work, it looks like I made a mistake somewhere ).